# How to assign a pointer in struct directly to a new struct?

Tags: c, pointers

can you help me please?

I want to manipulate a doubly linked liste that manage a bank accounts, but I don't know why it doesn't work even if I tried vainly to correct all my mistakes. Certainly, It's the first time that i use this nested structer and i don't know how to access from the main structre to the other ones (idt,idf).

2 Questions:

-is this method accepted "pnt->idt.dn.j_n" (pnt is a pointer on CompteBancaire)?

-when i traverse the main linked liste using a pointer and i want add a particular struct to my new liste (YoungCustomers), is there any possibility to assign the struct pointer to a new struct that i'll put it in my new liste, instead of assigning each element to it?
 Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h >
typedef struct
{  int j_n,m_n,a_n;
}dateDeNaissance;

typedef struct
{  char nom[15];
   char prenom[15];
    dateDeNaissance dn;
}identite;

typedef struct
{  int numCompte;
   char nomBanque[20];
}identifiant;
/* ------------THE MAIN STRUCT-------------*/
typedef struct
{  identite idt;
   identifiant idf;
   float solde;
   struct CompteBancaire *next;
   struct CompteBancaire *prc;
}CompteBancaire;
/* -----------STRUCT OF YOUNG CUSTOMERS----------------*/
typedef struct
{ CompteBancaire *Cpt;
 struct ClientJeune *next;
}ClientJeune;
/*-------------GLOBAL POINTERS------------- */
CompteBancaire *first=NULL;
CompteBancaire *first2=NULL;
/*---------- CREATE A BANC ACOUNTE ---------*/
void saisiNovCompt (char nom[],char prn[],int j,int m,int a,int numCpt,char nomB[],float Solde) //21:32
{  CompteBancaire *nov=malloc(sizeof(CompteBancaire)),pnt=first;
   strcpy (nov->idt.nom,nom);
   strcpy (nov->idt.prenom,prn);
   nov->idt.dn.j_n=j;
   nov->idt.dn.m_n=m;
   nov->idt.dn.a_n=a;
   nov->idf.numCompte=numCpt;
   nov->prc=NULL;
   strcpy (nov->idf.nomBanque,nomB);
   nov->solde=Solde;
   if (first==NULL)
   {  nov->next=NULL;
      nov->prc=NULL;
      first=nov;
   }
   else
   {  first=nov;
      nov->next=pnt;
      pnt->prc=nov;
   }
}
/* --------SAVE AN ACCOUNTE IN FILE-------------*/
void fichier (CompteBancaire *pnt)
{  FILE *Compte;
   Compte=fopen("comptBancaire.txt","w");
   fprintf("nom: %s\nprenom: %s\ndate de naissance: %d/%d/%d\nnum de compte: %d\nnom de la banque: %s\nsolde: %.2f\n",
           pnt->idt.nom,pnt->idt.prenom,pnt->idt.dn.j_n,pnt->idt.dn.m_n,pnt->idt.dn.a_n,pnt->idf.nomCompte,pnt->idf.nomBanque);
  fclose(Compte);
}
/* -------------- SAVE AN ACCOUNT THAT IT'S NUMBER IS GIVEN BY THE USER ------------------*/
void afficheParNum (int numCpt)
{  CompteBancaire *pnt=first;
   if (first==NULL)
      printf ("la liste est vide \n");
   else
   {  while (pnt!=NULL && pnt->idf.numDeCompt!=numCpt)
             pnt=pnt->next;
      if (pnt==NULL)
         printf("Compte non trouve !\n");
      else
         fichier(pnt);
   }
}
/*-----------------REMOVE AN ACCOUNT THAT IT'S NUMBER IS GIVEN BY THE USER--------------------*/
void suppCompt (int numCpt)
{  CompteBancaire *pnt=first;
   if (first==NULL)
       printf("la liste vide !\n");
   else
   {   while (pnt!=NULL && pnt->idf.numCompte!=numCpt)
              pnt=pnt->next;
       if (pnt==first) // remove in beginning
       {  first=pnt->next;
          free(pnt);
       }
       else if (pnt->next==NULL) // remove at the end
       {  (pnt->prc)->next=NULL;
           free(pnt);
       }
       else  // remove in the middle
       {  (pnt->prc)->next=pnt->next;
          (pnt->next)->prc=pnt->prc;
           free(pnt);
       }
       }
   }
   }
/* ------------------REMOVE THE ACCOUNT IF THE BALANCE IS LESS THEN 0 DH--------------------------*/
void suppInf00 ()
{CompteBancaire *pnt2=first,*pnt=NULL;
   if (first==NULL)
       printf("la liste vide !\n");
   else
   {   while (pnt2!=NULL) {
       pnt=pnt2;
       if (pnt->solde <0) {
       if (pnt==first) // remove in the beginning
       {  first=pnt->next;
          free(pnt);
       else if (pnt->next==NULL) // remove at the end
       {  (pnt->prc)->next=NULL;
           free(pnt);
       }
       else  // remove in the middle
       {  (pnt->prc)->next=pnt->next;
          (pnt->next)->prc=pnt->prc;
           free(pnt);
       }
       }
        pnt2=pnt2->next;
   }
   }
   }

}
/* -----------CREAT A LISTE OF YOUNG PEAPLE--------------------- */
void under35 ()
{  ClientJeune nov,*pnt=first;
   if (first==NUll)
      printf("liste vide !\n");
   else
   {  while (pnt!=NULL)
      if (2015-(pnt->idt.dn.a_n)<=35)
      {   nov->Cpt=pnt;
          if (first2==NULL)
             nov->next=NULL;
           else
           {  nov->next=first2;
              first2=nov;
           }
      }
   }
}
/* -----------------DISPLAY ALL ACCOUNTS---------------------*/
void afficage ()
{CompteBancaire *pnt=first;
 if(first==NULL)
    printf("liste vide !\n");
 else
 { while (pnt!=NULL)
   printf("nom: %s\nprenom: %s\ndate de naissance: %d/%d/%d\n num de compte: %d\nnom de la banque: %s\nsolde: %.2f\n\n",
           pnt->idt.nom,pnt->idt.prenom,pnt->idt.dn.j_n,pnt->idt.dn.m_n,pnt->idt.dn.a_n,pnt->idf.nomCompte,pnt->idf.nomBanque);
     pnt=pnt->next;
 }

}
int main()
{int n=0,c,j,m,a,numC;
 float S=0;
char A[15],B[15],C[15];
printf("-----------------Menu-------------------\n");
printf("1----------------------------------Saisi\n");
printf("2----------------------------------affichage par num de compte \n");
printf("3----------------------------------Suppression d'un compte \n");
printf("4----------------------------------Supp inf 00 DH\n");
printf("5----------------------------------under 35ans\n");
printf("6----------------------------------Affichage\n\n");
while (n==1)
{
    printf("donner votre choix :");
    scanf("%c",&c);
    switch (c)
    { case 1:printf("donner le nom:");scanf("%s",A);
             printf("donner le prenom:");scanf("%s",B);
             printf("donner la date de naissance jj mm aa:");scanf("%d %d %d",&j,&m,&a);
             printf("donner le num du compte:");scanf("%d",&numC);
             printf("donner le nom de la banque:");scanf("%s",C);
             printf("donner le solde :");scanf("%f",&S);
             saisiNovCompt(A,B,j,m,a,numC,C,S);break;
     case 2:printf("donner le num du compte:");scanf("%d",&numC);
            afficheParNum(numC);break;
     case 3:printf("donner le num du compte:");scanf("%d",&numC);
            suppCompt(numC);break;
     case 4:suppInf00();
            printf("suppression solde inf 0 à ete efectue\n");break;
     case 5:under35 ();
            printf("une nouvelle liste a ete creer\n");break;
     case 6:affichage();
     default:printf("tapper 1/2/3/4/5/6 !!\n");
    }
    printf("tapper 1:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? is your code working? or isn't it? Also, please choose a more readable style for coding, your code is very hard to follow, you put all characters next to each other, for the compiler it's easy to tokenize your code, but for human eyes it's all just one huge token, so use more whitespace, that's just advice of course.

Comment: You initialize `n` to 0. So the `while` loop in `main` dosen't execute.

Comment: I don't know what toolset you're using, but this shouldn't even *compile*. Neither `CompteBancaire` nor `ClientJeune` are properly declared, and code like `CompteBancaire *nov=malloc(sizeof(CompteBancaire)),pnt=first;` declares a *pointer* (`nov`) and a regular *instance* (`pnt`), the latter of which is then assigned a pointer, which isn't even legal. You're calling `fprintf` without passing a `FILE*`, etc.. Frankly, this code is a *mess*.

Comment: Indent your code and remove all the irrelevant parts.

Comment: Please just try to help me. I know my english is si bad but I'm trying to do my best. 
 Question:
I've one struct pointer and I want creat a new list from the first one(CompteBancaire), so how can i assign all the content of the first struct pointer to my new structer pointer (ClientJeune) without doing this:
 pnt1->solde=pnt->solde;
 pnt1->identite.nom=pnt.identite.nom;
...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but if you want to initialize a struct AND assigning it's adress to a pointer

Suppose you have

```
struct XXX
{
    T1 arg1;
    T2 arg2;
    T3 arg3;
    .
    .
    .
};
```

you may want to do something like :

```
struct XXX *ptr = &(struct XXX){arg1, arg2, arg3, ...};
```

maybe this is not the most elegant way, but it works.

Comment: Where `struct XXX` is? Maybe this is not the most elegant way, but it works. did you test?

Comment: @iharob I will edit my answer. And yes, I tested, I use this in a program.

Comment: I hope now you understand what I mean.

Comment: But this is actually a very bad idea i think, and can't think of a practical use case, though it seems to answer the question.

Comment: @iharob Yes, I understand. I do my best in order to answer the most correctly, but I'm still quite new here and in programming in general. :)